# Sketch "Trim Transparent Pixels" is unselectable/greyed out

Tags: svg, sketch-app

I am trying to export icon svgs to icomoon and am getting svgs with a huge artboard.  I believe i need to select "Trim Transparent Pixels" checkbox on the artboard in Sketch but it is greyed out.  I created a brand new project and it is still unselectable. Does anyone know how to enable this option/why it could be showing as unselectable

[image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting the individual layer?

Answer (score 1):

You should select **Background Color** and deselect **Include in Export**:
[image]